# Formatting apalike-url.bst link to reference

Tags: bibtex, formatting, apa-style

I am using [apalile-url.bst](http://www.i-cherubini.it/mauro/blog/uploads/images/apalike-url.bst) to get APA references formatting, but I want to format the reference link when I am using a URL, for example when I reference a URL I get.

> this is a url reference [StackExchange, ], this is a book reference [Jones, 2001]

As you can see if the URL does not have a year it still uses the [name,year] format, but I want the link to the reference to look like

> this is a url reference [StackExchange], this is a book reference [Jones, 2001]

Any ideas on how can I modify the .bst file?

EDIT: added working example

```
\documentclass[letterpaper,12pt,oneside,onecolumn,final,openany]{report}
\usepackage{url}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Test}

This shows the url \cite{google}


\clearpage
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{References}
\bibliographystyle{./reference/apalike-url}
\bibliography{./reference/refdatabasewok}

\end{document}
```

refdatabasewok is

```
@ELECTRONIC{google,
  author = {Google},
  title = {Google},
  url = {https://www.google.com}
}
```

Comment: What packages are you using to manage the references? Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The part to modify in the `opaline-url.bst` file is the function `FUNCTION {calculable}`. IN my copy of the file starts at line 1137.  The function must be modified as follows:

```
FUNCTION {calc.label}
{ type$ "book" =
  type$ "inbook" =
  or
    'author.editor.key.label
    { type$ "proceedings" =
    'editor.key.label           
    'author.key.label           
      if$
    }
  if$ 
  year empty$  % add this line
    {""}       % add this line
    {", "}     % add this line
    if$        % add this line
  % ", "       % this is the original line that has to be removed or commented out
  *            
  year field.or.null purify$ #-1 #4 substring$    
  *
  'label :=
}
```

The original style inserts `", "`, what you have to do is to insert it only if there is a value for `year`. So you can create a conditional that checks  whether there is a value for  the year: `year empty$` and if there is no value it does not insert anything, and it insert the comma and a space after it, i.e, `", "`, if there is a `year`.

Change the name of the `.bst` file after you modified it.

Comment: Worked after changing the name a few times