# Wrong style of citation using misc entry in bibtex

Tags: bibtex

I'm using BibTeX to cite the references in my LaTeX file. I have one entry (citing an url using the entrytype `@misc`). The default style is the author-year mode using the `apalike` style.

```
This is the entry \cite{url-1}.
```

The expected output is

> This is the entry [url-1].

But, I get the output as

> This is the entry [url-1, ].

The BibTeX entry does not have `year` field. This is

```
@misc{url-1,
key={url-1},
url={some website},
}
```

How do I eliminate the extra spacing for the year field. Even if I add an empty field for year like `year={}`, I still get the same format.

Comment: BTW: are you getting any warnings from `bibtex`? See the `.blg` file? It may be that for `apalike` year is actually expected, even for `misc` fields.

Comment: Do you use a citation management package such as `natbib`?

Comment: @daleif, I am getting warnings about missed year in misc fields

Comment: @Mico, I am not using natbib package.

Answer (score 1):

Since the `apalike` bibliography style is meant to generate authoryear-style citation callouts, the designer of the style file apparently didn't anticipate that there would be entries (of type `@misc`, say) that do not have a `year` field.

Here's a simple work-around: Load the `natbib` package, and use that package's instruction

```
\citeauthor{url-1}
```

instead of `\cite{url-1}`. As you can probably guess, `\citeauthor` outputs just the author(s), but not the year.

Comment: I have tried this option. It works fine but it overrides the other citations. All turned into numeric, rather than author-year format.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `biblatex-apa` and its `online` entry type. If there is no year, it adds `(n.d.)` (no date)  after the title, but that can be removed with a small patch if you don't want it.

```
 \documentclass{article}
\usepackage[style=apa]{biblatex}
\usepackage[american]{babel}
\DeclareLanguageMapping{american}{american-apa}
\usepackage{filecontents}%
\begin{filecontents*}{online.bib}
@online{Lear,
title ={Edward Lear Home Page},
url = {http://www.nonsenselit.org/Lear/}
}
\end{filecontents*}

\addbibresource{online.bib}

\begin{document}

\cite{Lear}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I finally managed to get a solution for this. I used a slightly modified .bst file "apalike-url" instead of "apalike" as mentioned [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/76462/formatting-apalike-url-bst-link-to-reference).